# VGA Splitter issues

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have 3 monitors set up at the moment, 2 that I use as and extended desktop and the 3rd is in the other room, I bought a VGA splitter to split my main monitor between the 2 rooms and it works but only if I plug in the second monitor after the PC is logged in. If I leave it plugged in and restart no monitors start up.
Is there any way to make it work on start up or am I stuck unplugging and re-plugging monitors.

System info 
Graphics card: NVidia GeForce 9800 GT (2 DVI output adapted to VGA)
Monitors that I'm trying to split are both the same resolutions. 
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate

Answer (score -1):

you could always create a script that switches to extended desktop mode then run that script on login through task scheduler.

You could use powershell ...something like this..

`$screen = @' 
    cmd.exe /c displayswitch.exe /extend
    '@
    invoke-expression -command:$screen
    exit`

save it in a directory e.g. c:\temp\screen.ps1

make sure your execution policy is set to remotesigned 
- open powershell.exe as admin and type set-executionpolicy remotesigned -force

create a scheduled task to run powershell.exe and pipe -file "C:\temp\screen.ps1" you can set it to run at logon.

Joe